# Keytool giving error for Illegal option: -alias

Tags: java, macos, keytool

I'm trying to import a certificate to my cacerts file in my java installation.

This command seems to give me the error "Illegal option: -alias myappProd".

```
$ keytool -import -alias "myappProd" -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /Users/myuser/Downloads/certs/javaprod.cer 
Illegal option:  -alias myappProd
```

How can I get past this issue?

Comment: same issue, I am using /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool instead did you get anywher with this ?

Comment: As suggested, try typing the command. Also try without quotation marks around the alias, they shouldn't be needed. Lastly, I always use the operation -importcert to import a certificate to a keystore (my keytool doesn't list the operation -import at all).

Answer (score 11):

This might sound silly, but was happening also to me.

I typed the command instead of using copy/paste into terminal, that worked.

Apparently the hyphen was different

Answer (score 2):

OSX includes its own certificate and credentials management tool, which name is also `keytool`.

The most probable cause is that you are using OSX's `keytool`  instead of Java `keytool` (as this provides the `-alias` option)

Use the full path for Java keytool on the command line, which is `JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool`

Comment: Same error. I used `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool` as the keytool command

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes around the "myappProd" in alias value.

so the command should be

```
keytool -import -alias myappProd -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file /Users/myuser/Downloads/certs/javaprod.cer
```

Answer (score 0):

When you face this issue Keytool giving error for Illegal option: -alias

Try typing the whole command instead of copy pasting the command in command prompt .You wont face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to type the command to resolve the issue. but ignore the first back slash "\" in the statement.
**Instead of**

```
keytool -list -v \\
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

**type this**

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```